Problems with \Ref and babel (The Latex Companion 3rd edition p.78)
Having just bought The LaTeX Companion Third edition, I'm testing the examples given in the book.
On p.78, the example treats of the using of \labelformat and \Ref.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}
%\usepackage{babel}

\labelformat{section}{section~#1}
\labelformat{equation}{equation~(#1)}

\begin{document}
\section{An example}\label{sec}
\Ref{sec} shows the use of the \verb=\labelformat= declaration with a reference to \ref{eq}.
\begin{equation} a = b \label{eq} \end{equation}  
\end{document}

if you add an
\usepackage{babel}

with whatever language you want you get a
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 11.

If you replace \Ref with \ref, all works fine again, but you loose the UpperCasing of the first letter, evidently.
Is there a way around this incompatibility ?
I've tried with [english]babel and [french]babel and babel with no option. I've tried with pdfLaTeX, LaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX ... same problem ...
Thanks

Welcome to TeX.SE!

nice first question, clear test file and it looks like a real bug.

You should report this to babel but a quick workaround is to restore the internal command
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}

\makeatletter
\let\@kernel@ref@saved\@kernel@ref
\usepackage{babel}
\let\@kernel@ref\@kernel@ref@saved
\makeatother

\labelformat{section}{section~#1}
\labelformat{equation}{equation~(#1)}

\begin{document}
\section{An example}\label{sec}
\Ref{sec} shows the use of the \verb=\labelformat= declaration with a reference to \ref{eq}.
\begin{equation} a = b \label{eq} \end{equation}  
\end{document}

babel redefines some \label/\ref internals so that active shorthand characters work, but this undoes that patch which seems confused by some of the
\Ref details. So some characters such as " that are made active by babel may  not work in labels after this change.

It's a little bit akward but it does the job ... for \Ref, not for the quotes ;) Thanks. How do I report anything to anywhere (babel in this case) ?

@paulbou https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues

@paulbou "not for the quotes" ?

\usepackage[safe=none]{babel} works too, see the documentation ...

@DavidCarlisle My mistake !! I've put some quotes after my \end{document} and ... they didn't appear in the pdf (and I can explain why) ! Thanks again.

@UlrikeFischer Wonderful ! There's just a little too much to read. I'll try to be more thoroughful next time !

@UlrikeFischer see the what????
